# R generate sequence for each pair in a vector

Tags: r, apply

I have a vector that could be of N length. For e.g

```
  x <- c(298, 307, 347, 374, 416)
```

I want to generate the sequence of number for each pair of vector like this:

```
  298:307
  308:347
  348:374
  375:416
```

and put that in a dataframe:

```
  temp_df <- data.frame(i = c(298:307, 308:347, 348:374, 375:416),
                    j = c(rep(1, length(298:307)), rep(2, length(308:347)), 
                          rep(3, length(348:374)), rep(4, length(375:416))))
```

I need  to write a function that can take any length of vector and generate the `temp_df`

```
  temp_func <- function(my.vec){

     temp.length <- length(my.vec) - 1
     temp_list <- list()

    for(j in 1:temp.length){
    
       jk <- j + 1
      
       if(j == 1){
      
         temp_list[[j]] <- 
          data.frame(i = my.vec[j]:my.vec[jk],                        
                     j = j)
      
        } else {
          temp_list[[j]] <- data.frame(i = (my.vec[j] + 1):my.vec[jk],                        
                                      j = j)
       }
    }

   test <- do.call('rbind', temp_list)

  return(test)
}

  temp_func(x)
```

Is there a quicker one liner to do this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you don't need any loop at all.

You can create a sequence between minimum value in `x` and maximum value and to get the `j` column you can use `cut` or `findInterval`.

```
vec <- seq(min(x), max(x))
data.frame(i =vec, j = cut(vec, x, labels = FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE))

#      i j
#1   298 1
#2   299 1
#3   300 1
#4   301 1
#5   302 1
#6   303 1
#7   304 1
#8   305 1
#9   306 1
#10  307 1
#11  308 2
#12  309 2
#....
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R solution:

```r
x <- c(298, 307, 347, 374, 416)

splitInts <- function(x){
    x1 <- seq(x[1], x[length(x)])
    unname(split(x1, findInterval(x1, x[-1] + 1)))
}

splitInts(x)
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] 298 299 300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1] 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 322 323 324 325 326
#> [20] 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345
#> [39] 346 347
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>  [1] 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 360 361 362 363 364 365 366
#> [20] 367 368 369 370 371 372 373 374
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>  [1] 375 376 377 378 379 380 381 382 383 384 385 386 387 388 389 390 391 392 393
#> [20] 394 395 396 397 398 399 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412
#> [39] 413 414 415 416
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

One option is `Map` to create the sequence of corresponding elements to two vectors created by removing the first and last element of 'x', then create the `data.frame` by `unlist`ing the `list` of vectors and the `rep`licated sequence of `list` based on the `lengths` of the `list`

```
x1 <- x[-length(x)]
x1[-1] <- x1[-1] + 1
lst1 <-  Map(`:`, x1, x[-1])
temp_df2 <- data.frame(i = unlist(lst1), j = rep(seq_along(lst1), lengths(lst1)))
all.equal(temp_df2, temp_df)
#[1] TRUE
```

It can be wrapped as a function

```
f1 <- function(vec){
       vec1 <- vec[-length(vec)]
       vec1[-1] <- vec1[-1] + 1
       lst1 <- Map(`:`, vec1, vec[-1])
       data.frame(i = unlist(lst1), j = rep(seq_along(lst1), lengths(lst1)))
     }

f1(x)
```

---

Or with `stack`

```
stack(setNames(lst1, seq_along(lst1)))[2:1]
```

---

Or as a one-liner

```
stack(setNames(Map(`:`, (x + rep(0:1, c(1, length(x)-1)))[-length(x)], 
            x[-1]), seq_along(x[-1])))
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
tibble(x, x1 = lead(x) + 1) %>%
      na.omit %>% 
      transmute(j = row_number(),
                i = map2(x, x1, `:`)) %>% 
      unnest(c(i))
```